# Redirect tomcat app to https in a secondary route

Tags: tomcat

I want to redirect my tomcat app called "app" to https in the url "mydomain.com/app".

I were cheking different post but these doesnt work in my case.

I have a website with a wordpress page, and this website has a tomcat server with an app.

I want to redirect this to https, and I did it, all the traffick is redirected.

But when I try to acces to my app url I recieve this on the navigator:

```
Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at secretshields.com Port 443
```

Do u know why it happends and how can I solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a wordpress page, you must have a reverse proxy (Apache2, NGINX, etc.) in front of Tomcat. Configure the redirection there.

Comment: In apache? But the problem is that when I redirect in apache it show me a 503 error. Only works if I access via "mydomain.com:8080/app". I the past I configure it using "workers", but I cant remember how I did it.

Comment: Your question lacks a lot of details. First you have to decide if you want: 1. access your page through non-standard ports `8080/8443`, then you should add the configuration of your `server.xml` to your question, 2. access your page through standard ports, then you should provide the information in 1. + the configuration of your Apache2 virtualhost.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer :) I want to move all the traffic to https but when I change the port to access via 443 port (in server.xml), all stops to work. Included the wordpress website, and the app isn't redirected. Only showed an error. Now, without the redirection, the wordpress website works via https, and the app works in mydomain.com:8080/app. ¿ Should I change again server.xml and share a caption of the fails?. And sorry for ask a lot